# Why is this question on hold?

Tags: discussion

Why is [Which is the top total tax-revenue increase in the Western World since the Great Depression?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4504/which-is-the-top-tax-revenue-increase-in-the-western-world-since-the-great-depre) on hold?

Why can be not answered in a few paragraphs?

It only admits ONE CORRECT answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's very hard to ask a `Which is the most...` style question without it being too broad.

Whenever I imagine someone attempting to produce an answer to your question, I picture someone trying to find a needle in a haystack.  You keep trying to reduce the size of the haystack, but you're still asking us to find the needle.

In order to find the most of something, you have to be able to first define, catalog, and enumerate said thing.

Taxes are difficult to define, catalog and enumerate because not only do nations tax, but so do states and municipalities.

It's also worth noting that It's hard to tell what counts as a tax increase.  Take the new deal for instance( the "tax increase" that you hinted at in your question).  The Deal wasn't just 1 spending bill that required taxes, rather It was a series of multiple bills, and determining whether just 1 tax increase among them is significant, or the whole set of increases is very difficult.

I think that you have to re-think the fundamental idea of your question.  Consider why do you need to know what the biggest tax increase is.  What got you interested in it?  If you think about that, you'll  probably be able to come up with a more concrete question that would satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: Isn't *(total) revenue-tax increase* an objective, well-defined numerical magnitude? I am right now looking at graphs of different countries. Total includes everything (direct, indirect, local, federal, etc). I cannot provide more details because I would then have to limit my question to specific countries or years. The total tax revenue is however well-defined everywhere.

Comment: By the way, I voted up by mistake.

Comment: You haven't told me why total, all-levels tax revenue is a too broad concept. You have not explained to me why it is not as well defined and concrete as GDP, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Even assuming you can get over the bar that SamIAm has set of not looking for a needle in a haystack, it is off topic.  This is better suited for History SE than politics.  If you get the answer to what it was on History then come back here and ask the hows, whys, and effects of the increase that would be on topic.

The most recent edit to the question removed the only on topic part(the why) and made it a simple trivia question which just makes it more off topic.

Answer (score 0):

1) it started off too broad by **time period**. Restricting it to 1930+ is an improvement.

2) it asked for which country in the **western world** without defining western world. (Does Cuba count?)

3) it showed a lack of research, asking for a **greater increase** than the FDR new deal, without showing what the [FDR tax revenue to GDP increase](http://www.usgovernmentrevenue.com/revenue_chart_1930_1950USp_15s1li011lcn_F1t) was. (WWII had a larger increase than the New Deal, so perhaps the "why" answer should be going to war)

4) it asked for how the country was able to achieve the increase. It might be better to split that into a separate question after an answer to **which** country has had the largest increase.